# What do you call these specific phrases used to introduce a dialogue?

Tags: creative-writing, dialogue

> "Hey, look at this. Why isn't it working?" **John said, passing the remote to Sam.**
>
> "You didn't press play," **Sam said, snapping up the remote.**
>
> "Hi everyone! My name is John, and this is my house," **the video began as John took his viewers through a tour of the house room by
> room.**
>
> "You sound really stupid, John."
>
> "Yeah, well maybe you should do it next time then," **John said, becoming red in the cheeks.**

It seems like they are different forms and I wanted to Google the terminology used to refer to these phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms you're looking for are **dialogue tags**, **beats**, and their hypernym, **dialogue attribution**:

> - **Dialogue attribution:** A fancy way of labeling the words attached to a line of dialogue that let the reader know who is speaking. Dialogue tags and beats are both examples of dialogue attribution.
> - **Dialogue tag**: A reference to the character (their name, title, or pronoun, usually) and a verb to indicate that they’ve spoken. For example, he said or Mary asked.
> - **Beats**: Small bits of action attached to a line of dialogue that infer that the speaker is also the person performing the action.
>
> [How to Write Dialogue Attribution (Medium.com)](https://medium.com/the-1000-day-mfa/how-to-write-dialogue-attribution-4b4137a6e9fd)

See more examples in other articles:

- [Tag, You’re It! Using Dialogue Tags Effectively](https://www.goodstorycompany.com/blog/dialogue-tags#:%7E:text=Dialogue%20tags%20are%20those%20short,dialogue%20that%20identify%20the%20speaker.&text=Dialogue%20tags%20are%20invisible%20and,tag%E2%80%94to%20identify%20who%27s%20speaking.)
- [Beats in Dialogue](https://writingmanual.pressbooks.com/chapter/beats-2/)
- [He Said, She Said: The Fine Art of Dialogue Attribution](https://bookblog.kjodle.net/2011/06/06/he-said-she-said-the-fine-art-of-dialogue-attribution/)

---

I came across these terms while researching for [my answer on English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/580058/191178) about the academic counterpart of this, which is known as "attribution tags" (among other names).